# 301 Permenant Redirect joomla :too many redirects

Tags: redirect

I have a server with multiple websites in same place 
Scenario is as belows
ABC/123
ABC/456
ABC/789

The 123 is pointed to www.123.com
The 456 is pointed to www.456.com
The 789 is pointed to www.789.com

now i want www.123.com redirected to 123.com.

i added below code in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.123\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://123.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it says too many redirects detected.

Does any one have a solution to this
Joomla version is 3.6.4

Comment: Your going to drive your server (and users for that matter) absolutely crazy, with all the redirects. You're already redirecting `123` to `www.123.com`, so don't do it again, remove this and simply redirect `123` to `www.456.com` instead.

Comment: sorry i have updated the information now, previously i messed adding the info

Comment: Joomla and Joomla version is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: @BrijeshSavaliya it appears that you have never accepted an answer to one of your questions in the Stack Exchange Network.  Please see that all of your questions are progressed to a system-recognized resolution (accepted answer, closed question, deleted question).  Please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329

Answer (score 1):

You have a redirect loop in your `.htaccess` file, you are redirecting from A to B and then to A.

A method to (uncleanly) address redirect loop situation in the `.htaccess` file is to add the following to your `.htaccess` file immediately after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

The above should ensure that a redirect rule is only triggered once.

*Update based on your update: Please check if you have an SEF plugin redirecting non-www to www. This where your redirect loop might be coming from.*

Comment: sorry, previously i messed up the question i have updated the question, so can you please look into the problem

Comment: @Brejish you will still have a redirect loop. You're going from A to B, then back to A